# How can we include 2 datasets in SSRS table with row and column grouping

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2016

I have 2 different datasets. one for current month and another one for previous months data. I want to compare the data under a single SSRS table. The SSRS table has column and row groups. How can I relate it and get a combined report from those datasets. Please help.

Comment: Why don't you get all data in 1 dataset and add another month field in the output fields and make your life easy?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using cumulative data, have you looked at using LookUp?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookup-function